# NSURLConnection get data from redirected URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I am using NSURLConection and its delegate methods to asynchronously get data from an online TTS api. Here is the URL I am trying to load:

[http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=hello world](http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=hello%20world)

The above URL redirects and give us an MP3 file which I need to download. I have used the following delegate method to download the mp3 file:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    if (connection == connectionToTTSAPI) {
        mp3Manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        localPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hello.mp3"];
        mp3Handler = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:localPath];
        if (!mp3Handler) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:localPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
            mp3Handler = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:localPath];
        }
        @try {
            [mp3Handler seekToEndOfFile];
            [mp3Handler writeData:data];
        }
    }

}
```

Since there are more than one NSURLConnection I am using in my program I have set an if condition to recognise the response is for which connection. But I was not getting the mp3 file, so I set a break point inside the delegate method and discovered that the the connection to TTS API is never getting a response. I think it is because of the redirection. I have seen the use of the following method when i went through some other questions, but I didn't find such a function in `NSURLConnectionDelegate`, and also as a starter with NSURLConnection I don't know how to use the method for handling redirects. None of the results gave me the clear idea how to use it.

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection: (NSURLConnection *)inConnection
             willSendRequest: (NSURLRequest *)inRequest
            redirectResponse: (NSURLResponse *)inRedirectResponse;
```

Comment: Looks fishy...how you are handling respons?..that too with how many "if" conditions?

Comment: If it is the if condition that confuses you, i use it since i use multiple NSURLConnections.

Comment: I always used AFNetworking(http://afnetworking.com) whenever multiple request/download featured..bcz it given me lot of control over the multiple request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That delegate method, for iOS, is defined in `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` and gives you the opportunity to control how the redirect is handled (you could cancel it, change it or return it unchanged).

In your case you want to let it request the URL as returned by the redirect response so a simple implementation would be:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection: (NSURLConnection *)inConnection
         willSendRequest: (NSURLRequest *)inRequest
        redirectResponse: (NSURLResponse *)inRedirectResponse {

    return inRequest;
}
```

I believe this should be the default behaviour though, so if the request isn't being processed, the problem is likely elsewhere...

Comment: sorry didn't get you.. where to return this?

Comment: Your implementation of the method you NSURLConnectionDelegate method you mentioned... I'll update the answer.

Comment: no, actually i didn't find that method `- (NSURLRequest *)connection: (NSURLConnection *)inConnection
         willSendRequest: (NSURLRequest *)inRequest
        redirectResponse: (NSURLResponse *)inRedirectResponse`
in NSURLConnection delegate. In which delegate is that method declared?

Comment: It's in `NSURLConnectionDelegate` for OSX - are you coding OSX or iOS? :-)

Comment: Ok got it fixed.. Looks like it was some problem with Xcode auto filling, ok, if I return inRequest, it will be returned to where? and how can I call the `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;` method using the redirected URL?

Comment: You don't need to call it, it will be called when the redirect response is received... Try implementing it... Updated answer - that method is defined in `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`. And tagged question with iOS

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35725/discussion-between-harikrishnan-t-and-mattr)

Comment: Can we move this to chat? I am still having trouble. Please join: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35725/discussion-between-harikrishnan-t-and-mattr